# Create Sharepoint filter to show documents expiring within 30 days

Tags: sharepoint, filter, view, sharepoint-2013

I am using sharepoint 2013 and am creating a document view to show contracts that are going to expire within 30 days of today.  I have a column called expiry date. Example, if today was Jan 15th, I want to show all contracts from Dec 15th to today.

How can I create a filter to do this?

I have tried expiry date less than or equal to [Today] - 30 but that didn't work as it bring back incorrect data.

Comment: When you say "It didn't work", you are being unclear. You should probably expand on this.

Comment: @kazagistar It didn't work meaning it brings back incorrect data

Answer (score 0):

The filter should read:

```
Less Than or Equal To
[Today]+30
```

It will not accept spaces in the formula.  [Today]-30 would be stuff that had already expired.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a time with this as well.  Try this

Due Date is less than or equal to [Today]+30

AND

Due Date is greater than or equal to [Today]

Answer (score 0):

Filter should be (based on your column name above):
Expiry Date > = Today and <= Today+30

This starts with the beginning date to the latest date (30 days later)